Can I use voting in nested cross validation to obtain estimator?
NEWBIE ALERT: First post, so be gentle :-)
I have looked at nested cross validation (as e.g. in this Medium article). I understand that I am able to obtain averaged scores from the outer loop and that those scores should be better estimates of generalisation than those obtained from an arbitrary train/test split.
Obtaining the performance of a model is great, but in the end not my aim. What I want is to make predictions, say in a binary classification problem. And ideally, I would like an estimator that performs like the averaged scores I obtained from the nested cross validation.
So, what I did was to implement a simple voting mechanism on the predictions obtained from the estimators in the outer loop.
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV, KFold
from sklearn.metrics import roc_auc_score
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification

# Example dataset
X, y = make_classification(n_samples=1000, n_features=20, random_state=42)

# Hyperparameters to tune
param_grid = {
    'n_estimators': [50, 100],
    'max_depth': [None, 10, 20],
}
# Inner CV for hyperparameter tuning
grid_search = GridSearchCV(RandomForestClassifier(), param_grid, cv=5, verbose=1, scoring='roc_auc')
# Outer CV for model evaluation
outer_cv = KFold(n_splits=5)
results = cross_validate(grid_search, X, y, cv=outer_cv, scoring='roc_auc',return_estimator=True)
y_predictions = np.ndarray((len(results['estimator']), len(X), 2))
estimators = results['estimator']
for i, estimator in enumerate(estimators):
    # Now we need to vote on each sample
    y_pred = estimator.predict_proba(X)
    y_predictions[i] = y_pred
    
# Now we can compute the average prediction
y_pred = y_predictions.mean(axis=0)
# And use argmax to get the most likely class
y_pred = np.argmax(y_pred, axis=1)

print("ROC AUC: ", roc_auc_score(y, y_pred))
print(classification_report(y, y_pred))

However, the performance of this estimator is near perfect, clearly indicating overfitting.
Are my assumptions wrong?

Some background and description of the “why” of the study is warranted.  Also, specify why a standard prediction method like maximum likelihood estimation is not chosen.

Dear Frank, thanks for your comment.
I am studying abnormal drinking behaviour of chickens under a health challenge. Owing to the nature of my dataset, this is a classification problem.
If I evalulate that performance on a single test set, I might not have chosen that test set "well" and my results might not reflect the real performance of my model.
Nested cross validation gives me a robust estimate of the performance of the model, but I would like to have an estimator that has (within reason) the performance that nested cross validation gives me.

Regarding the maximum likelihood estimation, I am not sure how to employ this for obtaining a non-linear estimator which performs according to a robust performance estimate.
Grateful for any pointers you might have!

It is very easy to add nonlinear effects.  See for example https://hbiostat.org/rmsc/genreg
